# jQuery $.post and json_encode is returning a string with quotes around it

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm using jQuery's $.post call and it's returning a string with quotes around it. The quotes are being added by the json_encode line. How do I stop this from adding quotes? Am I missing something in my $.post call?

```
$.post("getSale.php", function(data) {
    console.log('data = '+data); // is showing the data with double quotes
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`json_encode()` returns a string. From the [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) documentation:

```
Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.
```

You need to call `JSON.parse()` on `data`, which will parse the JSON string and turn it into an object:

```
$.post("getSale.php", function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('data = '+data); // is showing the data with double quotes
}, 'json');
```

However, since you are concatenating the string `data =` to `data` in your `console.log()` call, what will be logged is `data.toString()`, which will return the string representation of your object, which will be `[object Object]`. So, you are going to want to log `data` in a separate `console.log()` call. Something like this:

```
$.post("getSale.php", function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('data = '); // is showing the data with double quotes
    console.log(data);
}, 'json');
```

Comment: In any recent version of jQuery, it will automatically parse the JSON if you use the correct MIME type.

Comment: @Matthew +1, I understand this, since it is still is a string coming back, I assumed that the MIME type was wrong.

Comment: @Alex, in that case, you can also specify it manually with `dataType: 'json'`, and jQuery will still parse it for you.

Comment: Yea it worked. I do have 'json' at the end of my $.post call. Isn't that the same as specifying the dataType?

Comment: Yeah, you have specified json on the post call. You shouldn't have to do this. Try adding the content-type header as Matthew suggests.

Comment: JSON.parse is causing an error in ie7. How do i get around it?

Comment: In IE7, you have to include a copy of the [json library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying t do with the data that you're receiving? If you're simply trying to obtain a particular key of the JSON message, i.e. the "name" in "`{"name":"sam"}"` then (assuming you have a JSON Object and not a JSON Array) you'd be able to use `data.name` regardless of the double quotes.

Comment: I'm trying to insert the data inside an html tag once I get it back.

Comment: I am using json_encode(array()) to return the value in my php file, is that wrong?

Comment: @Catfish, you should also use `header('Content-type: application/json');` to specify that you're returning JSON.